# Textbox in HTA after text is submitted, remove text from textbox

Tags: vbscript, hta

not sure if this has been asked anywhere, (I cant find it)...

I made a little simple Google Search HTA file...

it works great no issue really but I want the text to disappear after ive pressed enter ?

I tried BasicTextBox.Value = "" after the search ...but this takes everything anyway except the last letter..

I hope im making sense, can someone help me please ?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search Google</title>

<HTA:APPLICATION 
ID="objHTAHelpomatic"
border="thin"
borderStyle="normal"
caption="yes"
maximizeButton="no"
minimizeButton="no"
showInTaskbar="yes"
windowState="normal"
innerBorder="no"
navigable="no"
scroll="no"
scrollFlat="no"
sysMenu="yes"
icon="htaicon.ico"
>
</head>

<SCRIPT Language="VBScript">

 Sub Window_OnLoad
 window.resizeTo 100, 100
  End Sub


sub checkEnter
With document.parentWindow.event
if .keycode = 13 then
Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.ShellExecute "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" & BasicTextBox.Value
Else
.cancelbubble = false
.returnvalue = true
End if
End With

  call removetext

End sub 

sub removetext
   BasicTextBox.Value = ""
end sub

</SCRIPT>
<body bgColor="gray" STYLE="font:8pt arial; color:white">

Search Google
<input type="text" onKeydown=checkEnter name="BasicTextBox" size="10">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `checkEnter()` is never invoked. In online assignment it should be: `onkeydown="checkEnter();"`, now the attribute contains a string ("`checkEnter`"). I think DOM properties are case-sensitive also in VBScript, there should be `.cancelBubble` and `.returnValue`.

Comment: @Teemu DOM properties in VBScript are not case-sensitive, but I agree it is a good practice to use them as if they are.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `removetext` in `checkEnter`:

```
sub checkEnter
    Const NORMAL_WINDOW = 1
    With document.parentWindow.event
        if .keycode = 13 then
            Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
            objShell.ShellExecute "https://www.google.com.au/search?q=" & BasicTextBox.Value
            call removetext
        End if
End With
```